# Maximum number from an array which is equal to product of two other numbers in that array

Tags: java, arrays

Recently, I took Linkedin placement test in which there was a question in which output for 4 test cases were wrong for me. I could not figure out what was my mistake becasue inputs/outputs were hidden.

Anyways here was the question:

> Find the maximum element from an array where product of any other two elements would be equal to that number and return that number .If no, such element is there then return -1.

Here was my solution:

```
static int maxElement(int[] arr) {
  Arrays.sort(arr);
  int max = arr[arr.length-1];
  int result = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      result = arr[i] * arr[j];
      if (result == max) {
        return max;
      }
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: What were the test cases and how (with what message) did they fail?

Comment: Your code could either return -1 or the maximum value of the array (if that number is the product of two other elements). What about if one of the other elements should be the result of the operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to find the possible maximum number in the array **and** the product of two elements in the array.
If I assume this, your code fails for this test case:
`int[] arr = {2,4,5,3,7,6};` , where the answer should be `6` 
Check this below code it will work for above test-case.
Just add one more reverse `for loop` to check the possible value and product.

```
static int maxElement(int[] arr) {
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        for (int k = arr.length-1; k >= 0; k--) {
            int max = arr[k];
            int result = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                    result = arr[i] * arr[j];
                    if (result == max) {
                        return max;
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: I should have consider this scenario(possible maximum number). I kept trying to rectify the problme by taking maximum number from the array. Now, I can not check this code because I have submitted the test. But your solution seems right to me.

Comment: Ya, such types of question tend to confuse you. So need to read the question twice or thrice to get it perfect. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        list.add(a[i]);
    }
    int maxSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
            if ((a[i] * a[j]) > maxSum) {
                if(list.contains(a[i] * a[j]))
                maxSum = a[i] * a[j];
            }
        }
    }

    if (maxSum != 0)
        return maxSum;
    return -1;
```